# jQuery addClass or css not working on specific conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addclass

I'm trying to color code span elements. I tried various solutions to similar questions but they seem not working for me. In the following code, only the `addClass` line is not working.

Code fragment 1

```
for (var m=0;m<software.length;m++)
{
    alert('software['+m+'] :'+software[m].priority);
    if(software[m].priority>=2)
    {
        alert('software['+m+'] :'+software[m].priority);
        alert("$('#software["+m+"]').addClass('redClr');");
        $('#software['+m+']').addClass('redClr');
        }
    software[m].priority=0;
    alert('software['+m+'] :'+software[m].priority);
};
```

I tried .css method instead and that too is not working.

```
$('#software['+m+']').css("color","red");
```

The span elements are generating dynamically according to some conditions. And it generates well. **Sample id for generated span : software[0]**

Sample:
Code fragment 2

```
if (checkedValues[j]==allValues[0]) {
    $("#softwareLeft").append("<span class='boldText'>"+allValues[0]+" :</span><br>");
    for(var k=0;k<software.length;k++) {
        if(software[k].calculation==1){
            //alert(software[k].name);
            if(software[k].combo!=1){
            $("#softwareLeft").append("<span class='softList' id='software["+k+"]'>"+software[k].name+"(Rs: "+software[k].prize+")</span><br>");
            };
            if(software[k].combo==1 && software[k].priority==0){
                $("#softwareRight").append("<span class='softList'>"+software[k].name+"(Rs: "+software[k].prize+")</span><br>");
            };
            software[k].priority++;
        };
    };
```

And already a class is applied named 'softList' to span elements which only contains the following css code

```
.softList{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

And both codes triggers under same button click like

```
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
   //Code fragment 2 
   //Code fragment 1
});
```

As I told, **I already researched well with this question and found many similar but somewhat different questions. This one strictly sticks into specific conditions hence posted separately.**

Comment: Put in JsFiddle link it is easy to debug

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kgh30ff4/1/ But not working because don't know how to include magnific popup css and js files into it. Except this bug, the code works perfectly on my local system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the id. HTML ID attribute value can be a combination of number and string if you try with software0, software1, software2 as the ID the code would work. the square brackets are causing the issue

or you can use with escaping the square brackets

```
$('#software\\['+m+'\\]')
```

Comment: Got it. Changed to software-1, software-2 etc and selector to $('#software-'+m). The problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

`[XXX]` means an attribute selector so you need to escape the opening and closing brackets in the id.

```
$('#software\\['+m+'\\]')
```

It is explained on top of the [selectors documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Thanks, Changed format from 'software[0]' to 'software-0' and switched id to class(because of the chance for repetition). Now it works like charm! Thanks a lot.